# how to Set cookie file as a flag when opening Chrome browser?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies

i tried to test my codes that work with cookie. i wanted to count times the user have come to our website and show different message in every time. 
it is OK in **firefox asd IE browser** but it is **NOT OK** in **chrome browser**.

i know there is not a wrong in codes but i do not know why there is that problem with Chrome?!

can you help me in this case?

Comment: please spend some time formating your code to make things easier for us.

Comment: @Joe Warner Hi. thanks for helping. i formatted them above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself.

i found out that Google Chrome doesn't accept cookies from web pages on the hard drive (paths like file:///C:/websites/foo.html) but there is a solution:

1- install a local web server (like xamp).
3- make a folder in htdocs directory (C:\xampp\htdocs) with a nome (e.g: "min").
2- put the file of your web page (eg: index.html) in that folder.
3- now run the Apache by your local server (xamp).
4- open your file as this url: `http://127.0.0.1/mine/index.html` in Chrome.

note: `127.0.0.1` is IP address of localhost.

Godspeed you